# How to select and compare a subset of models from a big set

Tags: model-selection

I have a model-selection question, any help appreciated.

I generate curves with known and well-defined properties.

I have a set of 20 thousand candidate models that I use to do non-linear fitting on the curves I generate.  Since fitting 20K models is computationally slow, I would like to get a subset of those models to only a few that would perform "reasonably well", say N models.

Question: how to select a subset of those 20 thousand and how to compare performance?

Example: One idea is to fit 1000 curves, and choose the top N best-fitting models, or the N most frequent models.  Then, with another 1000 generated curves, compare the performance of the full dataset with the reduced set of N in terms of overall variance and bias,

Any suggestions?  Any help appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
Ramiro

Comment: If you have such a large uncertainty about the curve (20K sounds a lot) why don't you go for a nonparametric model instead? My point is that if you don't have enough intuition to restrict the shape of the curve to a reasonable amount of models, perhaps it is better to let the data define this shape through a fully nonparametric model (e.g. by using Bayesian nonparametrics or some other approach).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Silverio.  Will think about this a little bit.  In principle this is more of a theoretical question, if you have N models and would like to only use a small subset of those (if possible) while maintaining acceptable performance, can one do it?